# Redirect back two (2) pages in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, refresh

I have an form on an edit screen and on submit I want to redirect back two pages.

Is there a way to do this in Laravel? I haven't been able to find anything online.

Thanks!

Comment: Redirect to the (named) route of that form edit page https://laravel.com/docs/master/redirects

Answer (score 5):

Laravel redirects back using either the `Referer` HTTP header or an internal session key `_previous.url` which changes on every request. So there is nothing in Laravel that specifically redirects back two pages.

As @kerbholz mentioned you could simply redirect to the correct page.

If you can't do that you could manually store the URL to redirect to in the session on the page you want to redirect to:

```
session(['previous-url' => request()->url());
```

And redirect after the form is submitted:

```
return redirect(session('previous-url'));
```

Comment: I was able to find away around it by including 2 different hidden input on the form with a key word in the value dependent on the previous url. Then in the controller, redirecting to a route based on the key word value. Worked great.